# EXTJS-Combobox (ComboBox List Options Not showing ? )

Tags: extjs, combobox, ext.net

ComboBox List Options Not showing ?
i added  combobox but the item not showing ;if i select any item it appeared as selected value but  when i check it by inspect element the div's shown as below whithout item ?? 
some times the items' div are not appears at all ? any help please ??

**note** : i added to the combo box some properties but not working 
**Stateful="true" StateID="SIDcb" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ClientIDMode="Static"**

```
<div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected"></div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item"></div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item"></div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item"></div>
```

the Combobox - deceleration :

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="cbItems" runat="server" Editable="false" Width="250" AllowBlank="false"
 CausesValidation="true" MsgTarget="Under" DisplayField="Name" ValueField="id">                     
<Template ID="T1" Visible="False" StopIDModeInheritance="False"EnableViewState="False" runat="server"></Template>
<Store>
<ext:Store ID="StrItems" runat="server" OnRefreshData="FillDDLItems"
 >
 <Reader>
<ext:ArrayReader>
 <Fields>
<ext:RecordField Name="id" Mapping="id" />
<ext:RecordField Name="TypeName" Mapping="TypeName" />
 <ext:RecordField Name="Name" Mapping="Name" />
 </Fields>
</ext:ArrayReader>
 </Reader>
</ext:Store>
</Store>
</ext:ComboBox>
```

Comment: Could you add the code sample with the combobox declaration?

Comment: Please check the deceleration i updated my question , thanks in advance .